# Facebook PHP SDK couldn't logout

Tags: facebook

I am using the latest facebook php sdk, but i found the method Facebook::getLogoutUrl( $params=array() ) doesn't work! getUser() always return my userid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can specify redirect url in your logout function and clear Facebook cookie and session after logout redirection, like

```
Facebook::getLogoutUrl( array( 'next' => 'your_logout_page.php' ) );
```

and in "your_logout_page.php",

```
setcookie('fbs_'.fb_app_id, ', time()-100, '/'); //clear FB cookie
session_destroy();
```

Hope it helps

Comment: wow,I will try it after back to home.I think this would be ok.